# Find all elements in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement something similar to an accordion in pure Angular.

I have a list of FAQs, with the answers hidden (via css display: none;).  I want it to work so that when you click on a question, then answer appears.  If you click on the question again, the answer hides again.

That all works fine using the following directive:

```
.directive('toggleOpen', function toggleOpen() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                if(element.parent().children().hasClass('open')) {
                    element.parent().children().removeClass('open');
                } else {
                    element.parent().children().addClass('open');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So the reason there's a bunch of parent().children() nonsense is the part I couldn't get working.

Let's say you have 2 Questions, 1 and 2.  When the page loads, both answers are hidden.  User clicks question 1, and answer 1 unhides.  Currently, when you click question 2, answer 2 unhides, which is also correct - but I only ever want ONE answer open at a time.  So if answer 1 is showing and the user clicks question 2, I want answer 1 to hide, and answer 2 to show.

I have a css class 'open' I am applying to unhide answers.  So basically - how can I find ALL elements having the class 'open' and remove it, then apply it to the element the user clicked on?

Is there a "pure" angular way to do this?

TIA

Comment: I understand your notion of a "pure" angular solution but why not leverage jQuery in combination with Angular?  You can then use jQuery's selector technology?  If you choose not to use jQuery selector, then you can always implement your own selector searching using the standard DOM functions and walk the DOM tree yourself looking for elements with a matching class.

Comment: @Kolban because Angular pretty much says "don't do that?".  It's considered pretty bad practice to try and combine the two, which is why Angular comes with it's own scaled down version of jqLite.  Completely different (and at times competing) mindsets.

Comment: This is a good discussion.  On the home page of Angular here (https://angularjs.org/) I read "It is fully extensible and works well with other libraries". See also the official FAQ ... (https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) which says that one CAN use Angular with full jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it all with template logic, no directive needed:

```
<section ng-class="{open: selected=='q1'}">
  <question ng-click="selected='q1'" ></question>
  <answer></answer>
</section>
<section ng-class="{open: selected=='q2'}">
  <question ng-click="selected='q2'" ></question>
  <answer></answer>
</section>
<section ng-class="{open: selected=='q3'}">
  <question ng-click="selected='q3'" ></question>
  <answer></answer>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  That's what I get for overthinking it.  ;)